# Understanding why relationship works

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to understand why something works.  I have a user model and within it I state that a User can have one Project e.g.

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Project', 'userId');
}
```

Then within my Project model I define a user belongs to a Project

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userId');
}
```

So the way I understand this, a User should be allowed only one project?  So within my Projects controller, I have my store function.  I wont go over all of it but I essentially do the following

```
$newProject = new Project();
$newProject->projectName = Input::get('projectName');
$newProject->projectValue = Input::get('projectValue');
$newProject->userId = Input::get('user');
$newProject->save();
```

Now where I get the input user, this is always the logged in users id.  So say I log into the system and I create a new project.  This project then has my userID.  This works fine.

My question is why does it allow me to create a second project with my same ID?  So if I am logged into the system, I can essentially create as many projects as I want under my name.  Does this not go against what my relatiohsips are defined as?  According to the relationship, I should only be allowed to create one Project.

I am really just looking for information as to why this is allowed?

Thanks

Comment: Laravel assuming you're adding/updating the current foreign key value.

Comment: But am I not adding the foreign key value by setting userId?

Comment: You're add/updating. ```$newProject->userId = Input::get('user');``` this line of code

Comment: A user can have one project, or many projects?

Comment: According to my relationships in my Models it should only have one project.  My question is why does it allow me to add more than one Project?

Comment: Because in O-2-O, Each record will be associated with a single record in other table, Unless if u define foreign key as unique record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **One to One**,

You're linking a `record` to another `record` in another table.

That means, You're checking for `single record` rather than entire table.

So in your example, As you defined it's a correct `One - to - One` relationship.

***Why it's adding new more than one project?***

As i said before, We are checking for a `single record`.

**How do i restrict that?**
use `UNIQUE` constraint for Foreign key

```
User table
----------
`id` int,
`project_id` UNIQUE,

Project table
----------
`id` int,
`user_id` UNIQUE,
```

> Example without Unique Constraint http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2b07/1/0

(Try to put same values it will fail to insert)

> Example with Unique Constraint http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dda24/1